# Proof verification of $(0,1]$ being not connected nor compact w.r.t. induced $\mathcal{T}_l$ topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am not sure whether my proofs are correct and I would appreciate it if someone can check them for me. The topology $\mathcal{T}_l$ is the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ induced by the topology basis $\mathcal{B}_l:=\{[a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{R},a<b\}$. The question is whether the interval $(0,1]$ with the induced topology (that is $\mathcal{T}_l|_{(0,1]}=\{U\subseteq(0,1]:\exists V\in\mathcal{T}_l\text{ such that }U=V\cap(0,1]\}$).

I reckoned $(0,1]$ isn't connected. Note that $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is open in $(0,1]$, because $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\cap(0,1]$. Then note that $\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$ is open, because $\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]=\left[\frac{1}{2},2\right)\cap(0,1]$. We have that $(0,1]=\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$, which is a union of two disjoint, non-empty open sets, hence $(0,1]$ is not connected.

I also reckoned that $(0,1]$ is not compact with the induced topology. Assume to the contrary that $(0,1]$ is compact. Let $x\in(0,1]$, then $[x,1]=[x,2)\cap(0,1]$, hence $[x,1]$ is open in $(0,1]$ for all $x\in(0,1]$. Define $\mathcal{U}:=\left\{\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$. Note that $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $(0,1]$. By assumption there exists a finite subcover $\mathcal{V}=\left\{\left[\frac{1}{n_j},1\right]:j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}\subseteq\mathbb{N},n_j\in\mathbb{N}\;\forall j\right\}\subseteq\mathcal{U}$. Let $\nu:=\max_{1\leq j\leq m}\{n_j\}$, then $V\subseteq\left[\frac{1}{\nu},1\right]\;\forall V\in\mathcal{V}$. Hence $\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal{V}}V=\left[\frac{1}{\nu},1\right]$. Now note that $0<\frac{1}{2\nu}<\frac{1}{\nu}$, which means that $\frac{1}{2\nu}\in(0,1]\setminus\left[\frac{1}{\nu},1\right]$, which is a contradiction, because $\mathcal{V}$ was a subcover of $(0,1]$. Therefore $(0,1]$ cannot be compact.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good. Note that your proof of the non-compactness of $(0,1]$ exploits that $0\notin(0,1]$, and indeed this also makes $(0,1]$ not closed in the Hausdorff space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal T_l)$, so it cannot be compact.

Comment: Thanks! So another proof of showing that $(0,1]$ isn't compact is simply showing $(0,1]$ isn't closed in $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_l)$? That would've been sufficient, considering it's ought to be not compact with the induced topology?

Comment: Yes, provided that you have the theorem at your disposal that states that a subset of a Hausdorff space that is compact in the subspace topology is closed.

Comment: Excellent; that's very helpful. Thanks for the clarification!