# How to show that $[0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ are or aren't homeomorphic with induced $\mathcal{T}_l$ topologies?

Tags: general-topology

This question has puzzled me for a while now and I just cannot figure it out.
The topology $\mathcal{T}_l$ is the lower limit topology induced by the basis $\mathcal{B}_l:=\{[a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{R},a<b\}$. Now consider $[0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ with the induced topologies
$$\mathcal{T}_l|_{[0,1)}:=\{U\subseteq[0,1):\exists V\in\mathcal{T}_l\text{ such that }U=V\cap[0,1)\}$$
and
$$\mathcal{T}_l|_{(0,1]}:=\{U\subseteq(0,1]:\exists V\in\mathcal{T}_l\text{ such that }U=V\cap(0,1]\}$$
respectively.
I am ought to show whether $([0,1),\mathcal{T}_l|_{[0,1)})$ is homeomorphic to $((0,1],\mathcal{T}_l|_{(0,1]})$. I have already shown that neither of these is connected or compact (for $(0,1]$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605705/proof-verification-of-0-1-being-not-connected-nor-compact-w-r-t-induced-mat)). I'm sure they're both Hausdorff, first and second countable, so there's not really a lot I see I can use. I just don't quite know where to start: I don't even know whether they are or aren't homeomorphic. From the fact that they share all these properties, I start to think they are homeomorphic, but I can't find a homeomorphism between them.

I hope someone here can give me a little push in the right direction. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  is there any $x$ such that $\{x\}$ is open in the first space?  What about in the second space?

Comment: No and yes. Thank you! That's brilliant.